# How to push values to PHP array variable through JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

[image: html output]

this this my page also i have one form also,it have a `clb` button for every alert,i have written a javascript function for each button(by looping) to pass the `ticket id`, so when i click `clg` this should store in php array variable to keep every ticket id,below is button code and  javascript function

```
<input value="clb" onclick="clb_this('116305');" type="button">

 function clb_this(vl)
  {
   alert(vl);
   }
```

this value should store in below variable

```
  `<input type='hidden' name='tic_array[]' id='tic_array'>`
```

please share your ideas,thanks

Comment: you mean you want to put `vl` into `<input type='hidden' name='tic_array[]' id='tic_array'>`?

Comment: ya,that's should be array

Comment: how about removing the `id` attribute and appending many inputs with same name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the below code

It will store the value in tic_array with comma separated and you can convert it into array with php explode function

```
 <script>
var clb = new Array();
function clb_this(vl) {
    clb.push(vl);
   document.getElementById("tic_array").value = clb;

}
</script>

<input type='hidden' name='tic_array' id='tic_array'>
```

Comment: Don't depend on `.toString()` to turn an array into something useful. If the array contains a string with a comma in it, you won't be able to tell which commas are data and which are meta data.

Comment: I hardly believe ticket id value will be comma separated I think @Ashok Sri is passing ticket id to the function clb_this().

Comment: While that's a relatively safe assumption in this specific case, a better answer wouldn't make the assumption and would be safe to use in the general case.

Answer (score 0):

Well its just my thoughts... If I understand you right, you want to get values from a javascript variable into an php array right?

Javascript is executed client sided and dynamically, so you could post your value per REST service to a php that receives it, each time user clicks the button...

In the php you have to create a session var to store your array and just push the value into it, every time the php is called.

Does that give you a hint?